# Can't redirect all homebrew cask outdated output?

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, io-redirection, homebrew-cask

I was writing a script to identify which outdated casks to upgrade, since `brew cask upgrade` doesn't upgrade all casks with a numbered version, and `brew cask upgrade --greedy` also upgrades those with auto-update.

But when I use `brew cask outdated --greedy 2>&1 | grep -v '\(latest\)'` to filter out casks with auto-update, it doesn't work.

My output of `brew cask outdated --greedy` is

```
google-drive-file-stream (latest) != latest
namechanger (3.4.2) != 3.4.3
quicklook-json (latest) != latest
timemachineeditor (latest) != latest
visual-studio-code (1.39.0) != 1.39.1
webpquicklook (latest) != latest
```

Whereas the output of `brew cask outdated --greedy 2>&1 | grep -v '\(latest\)'` is

```
google-drive-file-stream
namechanger
quicklook-json
timemachineeditor
visual-studio-code
webpquicklook
```

The version numbers are missing.

With `2>&1` I thought everything should have been redirected to `stdout`, but apparently version numbers are in neither `stdout` nor `stderr`.

I searched for similar problems and found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556226), in which the command outputs directly to `$(tty)`. But that's not what's happening in my case either. `brew cask outdated --greedy &> /dev/null` does eliminate all output, the command does not directly output to `$(tty)`.

Now I'm totally confused, where could those version numbers go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that using `script` as a workaround to capture the terminal output in a file works here, rather than attempting to redirect `stdout` or `stderr`.

```sh
tmp_file="$(mktemp)"
script -q "$tmp_file" brew cask outdated --greedy >/dev/null
grep -v "(latest)" "$tmp_file" | cut -d " " -f 1
rm "$tmp_file"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [brew maintainer recommends](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/12554#issuecomment-992449769) using `brew outdated --verbose`. Hence, redirecting the output isn't necessary (any more) and these should work better than a script:

```sh
brew outdated --cask --greedy --verbose | grep -v '\(latest\)'

brew outdated --cask --greedy --json | jq 'select(.current_version != "latest")'
```